# I am about to fail a required course due to difficulties caused by mental health issues. How can I save my degree?

Tags: graduate-school, professorship, grades, degree, health

So I expect to finish my master degree next August, and I was supposed to pass one undergraduate course to fulfill my degree requirements. I took this course last year and I failed it, so I had to retake it one more time.

I have been struggling with severe depression and anxiety for the last two years, and adding to it the uncertainty of the pandemic, my mental health got worse and I literally felt broken all the time, and therefore I didn't do well in the course (yes for the second time!). In order to pass the course, I need 65/100, and it seems my final grade will be something between 58 and 62 (all assignments have been completed).

The thing is that failing this course means I will have to leave the program, which will be so painful after all that I went through. Therefore, I was thinking of reaching out to my professor by email and explaining to him all what I was going through and asking him if it is possible that he gives me some work to do or something to pass the course. I feel like a failure for asking such thing and it is really pathetic, but I honestly have nothing in my hands. I just spend all day crying and self loathing.

Do you think professors in general can offer this kind of help? Is there a good way to approach the professor? Is there another way to save the situation? It is just that it was beyond me.

Comment: There is limited leeway of how much a prof can help you. You could ask him for advice of how to do better. You could also pay a student that passed that course with a high mark to tutor you. If you have had a mental health condition, most universities have now an understanding for this and the university may give you a dispensation to take the course later. Finally, maybe there are some compensatory credits you could get that would allow you to receive a modified degree. Any of these an option?

Comment: is there no opportunity to take the class a third time?

Comment: Depending on your institution's rules, there may be opportunities for you to retake the course and possibly even to have yourself retroactively disenrolled from the course.  However, we're in no position to determine what is possible in your specific circumstances and under your institution's rules.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Thank you for your response! Unfortunately, there is no way for me to retake the course since it is only offered next Fall and I am supposed to get done in summer. Also for my university, it is not allowed to have two F in your record. So if I don't pass the course, I will have to leave and this is killing me from the inside.

Comment: @cag51 I can't take the course a third time. If I fail it I will have to leave because I already failed it and I already submitted all my assignments, so I am not sure if the professor would be open to give me some assignments to do in order to pass or not :(

Comment: @BrianBorchers Thanks for your input. It is not possible to withdraw from the course, the only possible thing is to pass it this semester!

Comment: @cag51Thank you so much for your inputs. Yes, I am working with a counsellor and a psychiatric and I am already registered with the office of students with disabilities. The problem for me is that I can't take a leave of absence or anything. I need to get done with my thesis and all my courses before August 2021. If I fail this course then there is no way for me to stay in the program. I just wanted to mention that the course I am taking is for undergraduate, and while many undergraduate can retake the course, I actually can't and failing means all my work for two years is gone.

Comment: @M8season You are saying many things are "can't"s that I don't see a reason for "can't". You may need special permission or to take more time. Neither of these are the end of the world.

Comment: @BryanKrause I am fully aware of my situation. You can't find a reason for my ''can't' because you are not informed about how my university works. Not being able to pass the course means I should leave and for many personal reasons, leaving the program could dramatically affect me in many ways and I know what I am talking about.

Comment: I'm so sorry for you. Best of luck.

Comment: @M8season Often when we are closest to a situation we are least able to see alternative routes. That's one of the reasons it can be helpful to ask others, like here on StackExchange, for another perspective. If there is a rule that failing two classes removes you from the program it is more likely you can get an exception to this rule than have a professor change a failing grade to a passing one. If there is a rule you must finish by some date it is more likely you can obtain an extension. Etc.

Comment: @BryanKrause Thank you for your support. The professor hasn't assigned the failed grade yet, I was hoping he would give me some assignments or work to do in order to pass. I am not sure about the extension thing because I submitted all the required work, there is no work left, so how can an extension help me? I think the only way he can help me is by giving me an exam to do or something similar

Comment: @M8season I am suggesting you may need to finish your degree next year, and that if either regulations allow this or if you can get an exception to allow you to, that's a possibility to keep open. Mental health difficulties are rough. If you can overcome one by just taking one more year that's something you can be proud of. Especially with the impacts of the pandemic.

Comment: @BryanKrause Thank you! This is my last year in my Master degree, I already exceeded the normal duration, so I have to finish in August ( even though I know it is going to be very rough) My own problem now is this course, I just hope the professor can suggest some work to do or something to be able to pass and I am extremely extremely stressed :(

Answer (score 10):

First, the most important thing is to improve your mental health. Without taking the time to recover from this illness, these sorts of professional problems are likely to recur, even if you overcome this current situation. So, two suggestions:

- Begin (or continue) working with a mental health professional. In addition to the obvious medical benefits, this will give you some firm documentation of the problem, which could be helpful academically.
- Talk to your someone within your program -- either the graduate director or another trusted professor or someone in the school's counseling center. They can help you assess your academic options -- for example, the option of taking a leave of absence while you recover.

> Therefore, I was thinking of reaching out to my professor by email and explaining to him all what I was going through and asking him if it is possible that he gives me some work to do or something to pass the course.

I do not recommend this. I received these sort of requests at the end of every class I taught, and my response was always along the lines of "Too late, the course is over. It wouldn't be fair to the other students if I changed the grading scheme at this late time." While some instructors might be less hard-hearted than me, I think very few would be willing to give extra points for no reason, or to allow "extra credit" for one student only.

That said, there is still some hope -- if a student missed a passing mark by just a few percent, I would occasionally "round up" and award the passing grade. I would do this for every class, regardless of whether the students had e-mailed me with supplications.

> Is there another way to save the situation?

I would approach this from the other side -- see my second bullet above. The graduate director, or your school's mental health office, might be able to arrange for an exception, or a leave of absence, or some other work around.